# How to change the text of a drop dowlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdowlist in my view

```
<div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SubProcessId, "SubProcess")
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownList("SubProcessId", ViewBag.SubProcessId as SelectList)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SubProcessId)
                </div>
```

That has this model

```
namespace CTTModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class **SubProcess**
    {
        public SubProcess()
        {
            this.Risks = new HashSet<Risk>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int ProcessId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual **Process** Process { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Risk> Risks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

which appears in the view via this controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            try
            {
                // Risk
                **ViewBag.SubProcessId    = new SelectList(_db.SubProcesses, "Id", "Name", "Process");**


                ViewBag.RiskSeverityId  = new SelectList(_db.RiskSeverities, "Id", "Name");
                ViewBag.RiskFrequencyId = new SelectList(_db.RiskFrequencies, "Id", "Name");
                ViewBag.RiskRatingId    = new SelectList(_db.RiskRatings, "Id", "Name");
                ViewBag.RiskType1Id     = new SelectList(_db.RiskType1, "Id", "Name");
                ViewBag.RiskType2Id     = new SelectList(_db.RiskType2, "Id", "Name");

                //Test
                ViewBag.RegionLevelId   = new SelectList(_db.RegionLevels, "Id", "Name");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return View();
        }
```

These are the suprocesses that show in the dropdownlist

```
Past due collection
Dealer audits
Credit Watch classification
Reconciliation
Control
```

Every sub process can have on process

```
Portfolio Management
Finance
Test Modeling
```

Now I was asked to show in the dropdownlist not the subprocess name, but instead

```
     "<process name> - <subprocess name>"   
Portfolio Management - Reconciliation, for example
```

And I have the faintest idea how to do that.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var subProcessList = _db.SubProcesses
                        .Select(x => new 
                        { 
                            Id = x.Id,
                            Name = string.Format("{0} - {1}", x.Process.Name, x.Name) 
                        })
                        .ToList();

ViewBag.SubProcessId = new SelectList(subProcessList, "Id", "Name");
```

Comment: The string.Format threw an exception,                                         LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
I took it out, did a normal string concat and it worked. tks

Comment: If you add .AsEnumerable(), it works.                                                                                                                                                        var subProcessList = _db.SubProcesses.AsEnumerable()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Id = x.Id,
                            Name = string.Format("{0} - {1}", x.Process.Name, x.Name)
                        })
                        .ToList();